# Problem When Compiling with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I include the package tikz on my latex header, even if 
the package is not used at all, I get the following error at 
compiling time:

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.1131 \pgfdeclarearrow
                   {name=|<->|,   means={>[sep=0pt].|}}
```

where l.1131 is line 1131 of the file "tikz.code.tex"

A minimal example for this error is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

So could be the mistake?

Comment: Try to run `\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\pgfversion
\end{document}` and tell us what is the result, please. Since it says it is a problem in the TikZ you accidentally messed something up in the code, because for me (and for @Zarko) it works fine.

Comment: i can't reproduce your error.  you should have something else than this example.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The version is 2.10. Also, Zarko, incredibly that is the minimum example that gives a mistake. It is enough to use the command "\include{tikz}" and I get the error message, even if I don't use any tikz macro. (I'm using ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: I have a computer with Ubuntu 14.04, and the `\pgfversion` is also 2.10, but I can `\usepackage{tikz}` without any problems. So my guess is that your `tikz.code.tex` is somehow corrupted. Try [this](https://pastebin.com/9t1aNgXy). I copied the code from my version of `tikz.code.tex`. Replace your version (*make a backup first!*) by this one and see what happens. You can find your `tikz.code.tex` in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Please don't recommend the use of the `minimal` class. It is not suitable. Suggest `article` instead. (Or `standalone`, but that wouldn't be suitable in this case.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, I know, David Carlisle already warned me about that. I used the `minimal` class for this case only to find out the version of pgf, so it wouldn't be a problem. Thanks for the warning anyway `:)`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ah. That may not be obvious to the OP etc., though. (You may know it is safe in this case, but `minimal` gets read as 'for these minimal examples everyone keeps asking me for' :-).

Comment: @cfr Good point. I, for one, thought about it that way before I was warned otherwise. I swear not to publicly use `minimal` ever again `:)`

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got to solve this.

I uninstalled and installed texlive several times without success. 
Until I realized that the texmf directory was not being deleted when 
running

```
apt-get remove texlive
```

The solution was to manually remove /usr/local/share/texmf

Then I simply run

```
apt-get install texlive-full
```

and everything is compiling as it should now.

Comment: If you can reproduce this, you should report it to the maintainers of the `texlive` package for Debian, as it would seem that they are including the `tikz` package, without its dependencies and that's a packaging bug. However, I wouldn't expect them to install packages under `/usr/local`, so this may be fallout from something you did yourself (install `tikz` without all the bits it needs), in which case it is obviously user error and not a bug.